# Sockit.io can not connect to server by React Native

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I use the library `socket.io-client": "2.3.0"` try to use sockit on React Native.

I try the simple code on server side.

server.js

```
const
    io = require("socket.io"),
    server = io.listen(8000);

let
    sequenceNumberByClient = new Map();

// event fired every time a new client connects:
server.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
    // initialize this client's sequence number
    sequenceNumberByClient.set(socket, 1);

    // when socket disconnects, remove it from the list:
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        sequenceNumberByClient.delete(socket);
        console.info(`Client gone [id=${socket.id}]`);
    });
});

// sends each client its current sequence number
setInterval(() => {
    for (const [client, sequenceNumber] of sequenceNumberByClient.entries()) {
        client.emit("seq-num", sequenceNumber);
        sequenceNumberByClient.set(client, sequenceNumber + 1);
    }
}, 1000);
```

on client side:

client.js

```
const
    io = require("socket.io-client"),
    ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");

ioClient.on("seq-num", (msg) => console.info(msg));
```

`node server` and then `node client`

I can see `Client connected` on server side.

But it is not working on my React Native side even on Android or IOS.

My React Native code like this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");
ioClient.on('connect', () => console.log('connected on React Native'));
ioClient.on("seq-num", (msg) => console.info(msg));
```

I can't see `connected on React Native` and nothing happened on my server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I find my issue, there is no `.connect` on client side, the correct code should be `const ioClient = io("http://localhost:8000");`